# Select All/Cut/Copy bar not showing for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, long-click

When I long click the EditText I want to be able to do the normal things you would expect (Select all/Cut/Copy/Paste) but currently it only lets me paste. Here is the XML from the layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ChatActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chatListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4sp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Type to compose"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/send" />

</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

**Update** I finally noticed the action items in question, but the soft keyboard pushes the action bar up out of view. Oh, and I'm also testing on Android 4.3.

Comment: Do you have text entered into the `EditText` when you try bringing up the action mode?

Comment: Yes, I entered text. The soft keyboard pushes the action bar out of view and I can't scroll down to see it. Should I just paste my whole layout file?

Comment: What are you using for the action bar? Native? ActionBarSherlock? AppCompat? Something else? I haven't seen an app push the action bar out of the way when the soft keyboard appears.

Comment: I haven't done anything to change whatever the default would be.